# Keyword search to include Uniqueidentifier field

Tags: sql, sql-server, uniqueidentifier

I'm wanting to let a user search rows in a database by specifying a keyword to look for. There are a few fields I would like to look in for this keyword, one of which is a uniqueidentifier. The problem is, if the keyword is not a GUID, I get the following error message:

```
Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier
```

The SQL I'm using to run the search looks something like this:

```
// do not use
string sql = @"SELECT * 
               FROM [MyTable]
               WHERE [MyTable].[TableID] = '" + keyword + "'";
```

**WARNING: this is just example code - DO NOT write sql commands like this as it creates a security risk**

How do I write my SQL select statement such that it will not fail when `keyword` is not a GUID?

Comment: Why not simply check if `keyword` is a valid GUID *before* running the query? You can use a regex like `@"^[0-9A-F]{8}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{12}$"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    string sql;
    Guid id;
    if (Guid.TryParse(keyword, out id))
    {
       sql = @"SELECT *     
           FROM [MyTable]    
           WHERE [MyTable].[TableID] = '" + keyword + "'";    
    }
    else
    {
      sql = //search by other way
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?

```
string sql = @"SELECT * 
               FROM [MyTable]
               WHERE convert(varchar,[MyTable].[TableID]) = '" + keyword + "'";
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't really help you today, but may help future readers. In SQL Server 2012 you will be able to use [`TRY_CONVERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993%28SQL.110%29.aspx):

```
string sql = @"SELECT * 
    FROM dbo.[MyTable]
    WHERE [TableID] = TRY_CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, '" + keyword + "');";
```

But what you really should be doing is passing the parameter as a strongly typed GUID, and handling the error (using `try/catch`) in the client program when someone enters something that isn't a GUID.